# Are there any tools that I can use to analyse IIS7 failed request traces?

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, iis

Are there any handy tools that I can use to analyse IIS7 failed request traces?

Or more specifically, any tools that will tell me which FRT's have errors without having to manually open each one.

Or even better hive off the trace files that do contain errors for further inspection by said tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try installing Thomas's trace viewer:
http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2008/03/27/iis-7-0-trace-viewer.aspx

It uses IIS Manager extensibility to provide a viewer for FREB.

Comment: Thanks Carlos - now if only it would let me see wmsvc web deploy FRTs ...but then there's always .net reflector :). Useful tool for my support bods though.